# Dynamically insert content for a full text user search with JS and Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a search `input-field` and I want to display content dynamically depending on what the User types in it.

The Database hast 1,5k slots and I can allready search by giving a parameter

`?search_for=SOMETHING_TO_SEARCH_FOR`

where `SOMETHING_TO_SEARCH_FOR` is just a string. It does a full text search over the database and gives me the results.

I would like to replace the search results with the current shown elements inside

`<div class = 'slots-container' id = 'dynamic'>...</div>`

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class = "index-body">

  <%= link_to 'home', root_path, id: 'home', hidden: true %>

  <div class = "search_bar" id = 'search'>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
  </div>

  <div id = 'slots'>
    <div class = 'slots-container' id = 'dynamic'>
     <%= render @slots %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= will_paginate @slots, hidden: true %>

</div>
```

**index.js.erb**

appends the next elements to the div with the `id: dynamic` and removes the `.pagination` div which is included by `will_paginate` statement if we have no more pages so that my script for loading more pages gets a null reference

```
$('#dynamic').append('<%= j render @slots %>');


<% unless @slots.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

**main.js**

Loads a new page if User is only `100px` away from the end of the document,

with the `url: next_page` from the link with the `.next` class

```
var ready = true;
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $("img").lazyload();
  document.onscroll = function(){loadNextPage()};
})

function loadNextPage(){
  var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  var doc_height = $(document).height();
  var window_height = $(window).height();
  var window_bottom = window_top + window_height;
  var should_scroll = doc_height - window_bottom < 100; 
  var next_page = $('.next_page').attr('href');

  if (ready && should_scroll && next_page) {
    ready = false;
    $.getScript(next_page).done(function() {
      $("img").lazyload();
      ready = true;
    });
  }
}

function loadSearch(){
  var root_page = $('#home').attr('href');
  ...
}
```

As you see my `loadSearch()` function should set the param `search_for` and append it to my  `root_page` url and my `index.js.erb` should replace the current content of the document with the search results and also being able to still do infinite scrolling feature.

I think the controller is of no interest jsut be sure that `@slots` has the right paginated slot elements that needs to be drawn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it now as follows:

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class = "index-body">

  <%= link_to 'home', root_path, id: 'home', hidden: true %>

  <div class = "search-bar">
    <input class = "search-input" type="text"
                    placeholder="Search..."
                    id = "search-input">
  </div>

  <div id = 'slots-container'>

    <div class = 'slots-container' id = 'slots'>
      <%= render @slots %>
      <%= will_paginate @slots, hidden: true,id: "paginate" %>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

---

**index.js.erb**

`@identical_search` indicates that last search result is the same as the current one so dont do anything

```
<% unless @identical_search %>
  if (dirty) {
    dirty = false;
    $('#slots').empty();
  }

  $('#slots').append('<%= j render @slots %>');
  <% if @slots.next_page %>
    if(document.getElementById("paginate") === null)
      $('#slots').append('<%= j will_paginate @slots, hidden: true, id: "paginate" %>');

    $('#paginate').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @slots, hidden: true, id: "paginate" %>');
  <% else %>
    $('#paginate').remove();
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

---

**main.js**

```
var documentLoaded = false;
var dirty = false;
var pending = false;
var loadSearchTimer = null;
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  ...
  documentLoaded = true;
  document.getElementById("search-input").addEventListener("input", startTimerForUserInput);

})

...

function startTimerForUserInput(){
  if (loadSearchTimer !==null)
    clearTimeout(loadSearchTimer);
  loadSearchTimer = setTimeout(loadSearch, 300);
}

function loadSearch(){
  if (documentLoaded){
    documentLoaded = false;
    dirty=true;
    var search_input = document.getElementById("search-input");
    var search_for = search_input.value;
    var root_page = $('#home').attr('href');
    if(search_for && search_for !== '')
      root_page += "?search_for=" + search_for;
    $.getScript(root_page).done(function() {
      $("img").lazyload();
      documentLoaded = true;
      if(pending){
        pending = false;
        loadSearch();
      }
    });
  }
  else
    pending = true;
}
```

In `main.js` I use a Timer to only search 300 ms after last user input to limit the calls so that it doesnt search after every input. When the `getScript` returns `success` I am checking if a search request was submitted while the current request was processed to send a new request via `pending` variable.

`dirty` is set to true when the user search so that the `index.js.erb` knows to empty out the div containing the elements.

This runs smooth and I like it how it is.

I hope this will help someone in the future...

If it helps to udnerstand the whole picture, here is the controller:

```
class SlotsController < ApplicationController
  require 'will_paginate/array'
  @@last_search_content = nil

  def index
    @identical_search = false
    @hashtags = Hashtag.all
    if params[:search_for]
      search_str = params[:search_for].gsub(/\s\s+/, ' ').strip
      @slots = Slot.where("LOWER(slot_name) LIKE LOWER('%#{search_str}%') ")
      if @@last_search_content.to_set == @slots.to_set && (params[:page] == nil || params[:page] == 1)
        @identical_search = true
      end
    elsif params[:hashtags]
      @slots = slotsWithAtLeastOneOfThose(params[:hashtags])
    else 
      @slots = Slot.all
    end
    @@last_search_content = @slots
    unless @identical_search
      @slots = @slots.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end

  def show
    @slot = Slot.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

    def slotsWithAtLeastOneOfThose(hashtags)
      slots=[]
      hashtags.split(' ').each do |h|
        slots += Slot.joins(:hashtags).where("hashtags.value LIKE ?", "%#{h}%")
      end
      return slots.uniq
    end
end
```